# Image of polyhedral sets under perspective function( Convex Optimization)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

everybody. I am stuck in a problem in *Convex Optimization 2nd* by Boyd.

The problem is below:
[image]

The solution is below:
[image]

I am stuck in problem (d). I have no clue how the third inequality comes. I think that the general inequality means pointwise inequality. But where is  the relationship between each element ? Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality is elementwise (since it describes a polyhedron). However, there is only one $t$ for all equations, and that's what the third condition guarantees. If $h_i>0$ then $f_i^Tz+g \leq h_i/t$ is equivalent to $(f_i^Tz+g_i)/h_i \leq 1/t$. Similarly, if $h_k<0$, $(f_k^Tz+g_k)/h_k \geq 1/t$. Combining this, we get $(f_i^Tz+g_i)/h_i \leq 1/t \leq (f_k^Tz+g_k)/h_k$.

Define:
$$l = \max_{i : h_i > 0} (f_i^Tz+g_i)/h_i$$
$$u = \min_{k : h_k < 0} (f_k^Tz+g_k)/h_k$$
If $l<u$ (which is equivalent to your third requirement) Then any $t$ such that $1/t \in [l,u]$ will do.

Comment: Hi LinAlg, thanks for your answer. How can you guarantee that *there is only one tt for all equations* ?

Comment: @standerQiu I have updated my answer.

Comment: I don't know what exactly $= \in$ means, does the $u$ includes all the  $(f_{k}^{T}z+g_k)/h_k$ when $h_k < 0$? But that $t$ is not unique

Comment: I fixed the typo with $\in$. Indeed $t$ is not unique, but that's not required in the definition of $P(C)$.

Comment: But what do you mean in the second sentence *there is only one t for all equations* ? This assumes that $t$ is unique..

Comment: I mean that $t$ is shared and that you cannot pick a different $t$ for each equation.

Comment: Got it . Thanks for your patience.